# Assigning wires deep in a nested set of modules

Tags: variable-assignment, verilog, version-control, hdl

I have a wire that is about 4 levels deep and I really don't want the hassle of having to propagate it up the hierarchy. Is there any way to assign the wire using some sort of referencing? I know I can access the wire by typing:

```
cca.cpu0.cca3_cpu.nc1_cp_checkpoint
```

but

```
assign cca.cpu0.cca3_cpu.nc1_cp_checkpoint = checkpoint;
```

doesn't work

Anyone know of any way to do it?

Comment: Related and potentially of interest: it's possible to do this using synthesisable constructs by taking advantage of static variables in functions to propagate connections https://github.com/chiggs/hidden_wires

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have not shown sufficient code for anyone to reproduce your problem, nor have you revealed any details regarding your problem, all we can do is guess.

My guess is that `nc1_cp_checkpoint` is declared as a `reg` inside your `cca3_cpu` instance. You can not assign a value to a `reg` using a continuous assignment.  Try to use a procedural assignment (inside an `initial` or `always` block), for example:

```
initial begin
    cca.cpu0.cca3_cpu.nc1_cp_checkpoint = checkpoint;
end
```

If this doesn't solve your problem:

1. Show more **relevant** code
2. Elaborate on "doesn't work".  Show your error message, if any.

Update:  Another potential issue arises if `nc1_cp_checkpoint` is a continuously-driven `wire` inside your `cca3_cpu` instance.  In that case, your second `assign` might cause contention, which would make the value go unknown (`x`).  You might be able to avoid that issue using `force` and `release`.

Comment: Thanks! I looked it up and realized that since I was simulating I needed to use force and release. nc1_cp_checkpoint is a wire, and it was inside an initial block in my testbench, sorry I should of made that more clear.

Answer (score 2):

From your tag, you seem to be indicating that you're using VCS.  Are you getting a:

```
Error-[XMRE] Cross-module reference resolution error
Cross module resolution failed, token BLAH'. 
Originating module 'foo'. "foo.v", 666:
```

That would indicate that your path isn't correct.

Cross-module references do work, but they may not be enabled if you're constraining your design to synthesizable constructs.  Look up "cross-module reference" in the VCS user guide.

Comment: While this wasn't the problem, I didn't know about this, so thanks for pointing it out!